# Swift 3.0 - UIButton Label height has height zero

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding a simple Update Button to a page on my app. The button has an imageView and should have a title "Update Now" on top of the view.

In the view hierarchy I can see the UILabel as a subview of UIButton. But printing the description of the UILabel returns frame

```
(250 20; 283 0).
```

This is my code

```
let updateButton = UIButton()
updateButton.frame = CGRect(x: centreX(parent: self.view, width: 150), y: 200, width: 150, height: 40)
updateButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"my-image"), for: .normal)

updateButton.setTitle("Update Now", for: .normal)
updateButton.titleLabel?.sizeToFit()
updateButton.titleLabel?.frame = updateButton.frame
updateButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
self.view.addSubview(updateButton)
```

I thought both of the lines

```
updateButton.titleLabel?.sizeToFit()
updateButton.titleLabel?.frame = updateButton.frame
```

would change the height of the label's frame. Is there something I am missing here?

Using Swift 3.0 and iOS 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue. From UIButton Documentation

> Supply a title string or image; size the button appropriately for your content.

This implies that only 1 of these properties can be set. As I was setting the image first, this is what was being shown. And is the reason I could not see the label.

As I work around I have 2 solutions:

**Firstly - Use The Title and set a background color**

```
updateButton.setTitle("Update Now", for: .normal)
updateButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
updateButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "my-image")!)
```

This is what I used. I had to scale the background image in order to fit the view though.

**Alternatively - Create a new image combining the Update Now text**

```
updateButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"my-new-image"), for: .normal)
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

i think you need to set background image instead of image like as follows

```
updateButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "my-image"), for: .normal)
```

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you. This was a mistake of mine while copying over the code and altering it to remove my images actual name.