# When I create image for button the title for the button is not shown anymore?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, uiimage

```
button.setTitle("Like", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(red: 143, green: 150, blue: 163), for: .normal)
button.setImage(UIImage(named:"like"), for: .normal)
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 8 , bottom:0, right: 0)
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: likeButton)
addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(44)]|", views:likeButton)
```

if I remove the line " `button.setImage(UIImage(named:"like"), for: .normal)`" then the title shows properly.how can I show both the title and the image at the same time?

Comment: Your edge insets are most likely causing the title to disappear. An edge inset of 40 is pretty extreme!

Comment: it still doesnt work

Comment: How big is the actual image?

Comment: it is 375*360 pixels

Comment: Thats pretty huge. Is the button going to be anywhere near that size on screen? Try making the image be the exact size you want it to be.

Comment: Exactly like you did. I think your problem is the image size combined with the edge insets. I'd need to see more of the project to help you better. Good luck.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45102584/934710

Comment: You did not adjust the image size in constraints. You adjusted the button size, thus making it even harder for both the image and the text to appear. Your button is too small and your image is too big! Think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of UIButton and override

```
class MyButton : UIButton {
    override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: self.bounds.size.height/2, width: self.bounds.size.width/2, height: self.bounds.size.height)
    }
    
    override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: (self.bounds.size.width/2 + 5), y: self.bounds.size.height/2, width: (self.bounds.size.width/2 - 5), height: self.bounds.size.height)
    }
}
```

The rect calculated for title and image are relative to the bounds of UIButton so no matter what size UIButton will take they will adjust to match their size as per calculation.

In the picture below abcd is title and whatever u see on right side is buttons title image.

[image]

**Pitfalls**

`UIButton`s respect the intrinsic size which means they will take the size narrated by the title and title image unless they have sufficient auto layout constraints on them which directly/indirectly decides their frame.

If you set a huge image as button title or set a very tiny image as button title image you might see a very big or very small button respectively unless you have width & height or trailing, leading and top, bottom constraints.

Because the title and images rects are calculated relative to the bounds of Button its very important to make sure u have enough constraints which will decide the size of button correctly or making sure u have perfectly sized image which will make sure button takes appropriate size.

Happy coding